# Changing/deleting cache causes system crash?

Tags: magento-1.7, cache, backend, permissions

this is not my first post about this issue, but i've finally found what could be the cause of my problems.
It seems that deleting or "changing" my magento cache causes my site to crash.

- I've deleted my cache, from backend and var/cache, and in both case
  the site crashes. Furthermore even only looking at the cache page in
  the backend (not changing a thing, but only accessing at that page)
  causes the error.
- Saving anything on configuration page causes the    crash too, once
  i've restored the site i noticed that i can see my    changing in
  backend, but not on frontend, so i suppose this is    another cache
  issue.
- Tried to delete an extension many times and in    many ways, same
  result, site crashes.

I thought to a permissions error, but both to me and my server provider everything seems ok, i've also a test site (cloned by this one), in the same server on a different subdomain, the permissions are the same, but there's no error there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel kinda dumb.
I've found the issue, in my database, inside `core_config_data` both `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/unsecure/base_url` had the url without a "/" at the end.
Flushing the cache meant searching the resources inside `domain.itskin/...` instead of `domain.it/skin...`